# How do I get this element in css

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a website using wordpress and WPBakery. I am trying to give a specific style to the web page so I need to access an element of the web page. 
What I need to achieve is this 
[image]
To have every row aligned in the center with and specific width, I can do this using this css code

```
.RowInterior {
     width: 1000px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

But the problem is that I don´t know how to access the element that I need to assign that rule to.

This is the link of the web page http://13.59.219.129/SC/nuestro-compromiso/ there you will find 4 elements with the class "RowInterior" I need to access the element before, with the class "wpb_wrapper". I am adding the class "RowInterior" through the extra class name option inside WPBakery.

This is how the code is generated

```
 <div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc- 
    stretch-content="true"
   class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1565904278366 vc_row-has-fill 
    vc_row-no-padding"
   style="position: relative; left: -391.008px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 2352px;">
   <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 text-align-center">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
         <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid RowInterior">
```

I need to access the element above the element with the class "RowInterior"

Comment: Please share a section of the target code from the site in your question itself.

Comment: @ObsidianAge updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more specific selector for example this one

```
.vc_custom_1565904278366 > .wpb_column > .vc_column-inner > .wpb_wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

I just visited your website and I accessed the inspect element so I can edit your css code.

Just two lines of code could be of help to you:

```
.vc_column-inner{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

The `vc_column-inner` `div` element is the child of the parent `div` `wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12`

Hope this helps!